# Prove $f(x_1, x_2, x_3,x_4) = \frac{x_1}{x_1 x_3+x_2 x_4}$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, rational-functions

> Prove that the function $f : \mathbb R_{>0}^4 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = \dfrac{x_1}{x_1 x_3+x_2 x_4}$$ is convex.

I am not sure if this assertion is correct but I do believe it is. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: are $\alpha, \beta$ constants? or are they also variables of $f$

Comment: @chemist: edited the question; all arguments of the function $f$ are variables

Comment: @Shogun: I calculated the hessian of the function; its determinant is equal to zero; is this enough to show the hessian is positive semi-definite (which i think will show the convexity)?

Answer (score 1):

If you sort $ x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 $ in a vector, it will be of the form linear-over-quadratic. This function is not convex.

Answer (score 1):

If your function were convex, so would sections through it, such as $x\mapsto f(x,1,1,1)=x/(x+1)$.  This function has *negative* second derivative, and hence is *not convex* and neither is your original $f$.

Comment: all the arguments of $f$ are variables; see the edit ..